# Cannot change hostname of raspberry pi in local network

Tags: raspberry-pi, hostname, router, host-name-resolution

I have a clean install of the debian-based OSMC os on a raspberry pi.
I've manually set a static IP:

```
$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=-28605<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 39310  bytes 7976110 (7.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11710  bytes 2444978 (2.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And I've set the hostname as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
cerebro

$ cat /etc/hosts
::1             cerebro localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
127.0.1.1       cerebro

127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

And yet, when I scan the host with nmap, I see the host reported as **osmc.connect**:

```
$ nmap -sP 192.168.1.3

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-03-24 21:22 GMT
Nmap scan report for osmc.connect (192.168.1.3)
Host is up (0.032s latency).
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

What I feel is somehow related is that when I ping either **192.168.1.1**, **osmc.connect** or **cerebro.local**, I get:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.3
PING 192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.16 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.61 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.63 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.88 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4.28 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4.32 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4.32 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4.55 ms (DUP!)
```

I spent all day trying to figure this out to no avail.

1. Where is this **osmc.connect** hostname coming from and how to get rid of it?
2. Why do I have these duplicate pings and how to get rid of them?

It's worth mentioning I've recently switched to Vodafone (Huawei 963168_HUAWEIVOX25) and I'm highly suspicious that it is causing all this trouble.

I have another raspberry on he network with another hostname, and the router shows it in the connected devices as **computer-3.connect** ?!?

---

### UPDATE:

I changed the SSID of the wifi network and once reconnected, the router was already seeing the host as **cerebro.connect**, but the duplicate pings were still there.

### SECOND UPDATE:

The following morning the duplicate updates are gone and all looks ok.
However, I wanted to understand what happened, so I changed back the hostname in **/etc/hostname** and **/etc/hosts** to **osmc** and rebooted. 
**systemctl status avahi-daemon** correctly shows the hostname as **osmc**. However in the router's list of devices, I still see it as **cerebro.connect**.
Then I renamed the hostname back to **cerebro** and rebooted again.
And now the **(DUP!)** pings are back!

```
$ sudo systemctl status avahi-daemon
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-03-25 10:24:15 BST; 11min ago
 Main PID: 244 (avahi-daemon)
   Status: "avahi-daemon 0.6.32 starting up."
   CGroup: /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service
           ├─244 avahi-daemon: running [cerebro.local]
           └─267 avahi-daemon: chroot helper

Mar 25 10:24:15 cerebro avahi-daemon[244]: Loading service file /services/ssh.service.
Mar 25 10:24:15 cerebro avahi-daemon[244]: Loading service file /services/udisks.service.
Mar 25 10:24:15 cerebro avahi-daemon[244]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Mar 25 10:24:15 cerebro avahi-daemon[244]: Server startup complete. Host name is cerebro.local. Local service cookie is
Mar 25 10:24:15 cerebro avahi-daemon[244]: Service "cerebro" (/services/udisks.service) successfully established.
Mar 25 10:24:15 cerebro avahi-daemon[244]: Service "cerebro" (/services/ssh.service) successfully established.
Mar 25 10:24:15 cerebro avahi-daemon[244]: Service "cerebro" (/services/sftp.service) successfully established.
Mar 25 10:24:17 cerebro avahi-daemon[244]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.
Mar 25 10:24:17 cerebro avahi-daemon[244]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Mar 25 10:24:17 cerebro avahi-daemon[244]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.3 on wlan0.IPv4.
```

It's like the router is caching the hostname.

Also the second Rpi I have (which is on a wired connection) is still seen by the router as **computer-3.connect** and I still have no idea how to change that. **systemctl status avahi-daemon** shows the correct hostname

Comment: It is not the fault of Vodafone you not being aware how zeroconf/avahi/mDNS works

Comment: Try avahi-set-host-name cerebro

Comment: On the Rpi, what is the output of `sudo systemctl status avahi-daemon`

Comment: avahi-set-host-name is not available.
Please see my updates